# Video file with timestamps starting at gt zero with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp

**The problem:**
Among multiple subtitle files find the one that matches the specific video file based on just a short transcoded fragment of it, which has smaller frame size and different codecs. Using the original movie file is not possible.

**Desired solution:**
Transcode a short fragment from the middle of the video file with timestamps in the fragment set to their original values, e.g. `00:30:00 -> 00:31:00` instead of standard `00:00:00 -> 00:01:00`. This would allow to open the fragment in a video player adding different subtitle files. The original timestamps would make it possible for the player to show the proper phrases from the subtitle file.

**Question:**
Is it possible at all to have a video file starting from a non-zero timestamp so that subtitles are showed properly? If so, how it should be done in ffmpeg?

I've tried to use the `-copyts` flag, but I get output file with zero duration when setting `-ss 1800` for the input files and `-t 60` for the output file.

Comment: Along with `-copyts`, you need to add `-start_at_zero` (both before `-i`). Test this because it will depend on how the player handles sub timecodes - as duration into playback _or_ media timestamp?

Comment: Did you ever achieve any positive result with this? I find that no matter what I do, my output starts at zero timestamps. Curious if you found an answer elsewhere.

Comment: @Sander Unfortunately not, so far.